# Having data with Self Referencing Relationship

Tags: t-sql

I have Tree like this

```
Folder0
|
|__Folder1
|  |
|  |_______Folder2
|  |        |_______Folder3
|  |        |_______Folder4
|  |_______Folder5
|  |_______Folder6
|__Folder7
```

Fields of the table are like this   Id, fld_Id, Name, which fld_Id is the parent Id of the folder

```
 Id    ,    fld_Id     ,   Name
________________________________
 1           Null          Folder0
 2           Null          Folder7
 3            1            Folder1
 4            3            Folder2
 5            4            Folder3
 6            4            Folder4
 7            3            Folder5
 7            3            Folder6
```

how can I get the List of the all directories which are located under the Folder1
which would be

```
 Id    ,    fld_Id     ,   Name
________________________________
 3            1            Folder1
 4            3            Folder2
 5            4            Folder3
 6            4            Folder4
 7            3            Folder5
 7            3            Folder6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using recursive CTE like below :

```
;with CTE as
(
   SELECT  Id,fld_Id,Name FROM Test t1 WHERE Id = 3

   UNION ALL

   SELECT  t1.Id, t1.fld_Id, t1.Name
   FROM Test t1
   INNER JOIN CTE ON t1.fld_Id = CTE.Id
)

SELECT * FROM CTE order by Id
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29d8d/2)**